# Does Amazon offer a way to reserve AWS S3 bucket name prefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS S3 "bucket" names must be globally unique.  I gather that a common convention is to use *mydomain-tld-* as a prefix.

Conventions are cool but standards are stronger.

Does Amazon offer a service for customers to reserve prefixes for S3 bucket names? Do they offer any conflict resolution or acceptable use challenge mechanism if someone is found "squatting" on a prefix, such as **my_domain-tld-** (in other words where the provenance of the prefix is blatant)?

Comment: Not that I have seen.  I even tried creating the bucket (netflix-com-brooks and netflix.com-brooks), figuring if such a service exists, Netflix would have it.

Comment: Seems like they're leaving money on the table by not offering such a service. :)

Comment: 1. reserve 100 buckets. 2. ??? 3. profit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is **No**. Amazon does not offer a way to reserve a **bucket** or **bucket prefix**. Since it doesn't cost anything to create a bucket, create all possible buckets that you may need (if you exceed the 100 buckets limit, just submit a request to increase it.)

Bucket squatting is becoming a big issue and AWS is not addressing it. There have been complaints about squatters creating bucket/bucket-prefix names of popular domains. The only thing you can do is to send a mail to AWS: [NOTICE AND PROCEDURE FOR MAKING CLAIMS OF COPYRIGHT INFRINGEMENT](http://aws.amazon.com/terms/#notice-and-procedure-for-making-claims-of-copyright-infringement)

Good luck.

Comment: This is a huge pain in situations where we create buckets dynamically have to check for duplicity :(